# Can anyone help me identify the date of manufacture of this drywall?

Tags: drywall

[image]

Hi there. I’m trying to determine whether this drywall was installed during a remodel on my home back in 2004 or whether it was installed by the people who recently sold the house to us (who lived in the house from 2011 to 2018) during a repair. I don’t see a date stamp but am wondering if this manufacturing info is sufficient to identify when it was manufactured?

Comment: Why? Is there a problem it is totally legal and no disclosure requirement to replace wall coverings, so why do you ask?  Fyi I have replaced entire tools and houses with new sheetrock where there were tons of DIY patches and old plaster lath. So the reason why would be helpful and the entire code on the sheets. But even that only shows the date the sheetrock was made I have 5+ full sheets in my garrage that are close to 5 years old.

Comment: Hi Ed. We just bought this house 6 months ago and recently discovered black mold in an entire section that’s being caused by shoddy construction. It’s going to cost us a fortune to remediate the mold + redo the drywall + fix the grading/slope in the yard + install proper drainage. Several people have said it’s unlikely the sellers were unaware of the water intrusion problem. The only way we could get compensated is if we can show that they knew about the problem but failed to disclose it. If the drywall was replaced in that area while the owned it, that would suggest they were aware. Thx.

Comment: Ok this is a reason to ask but having been in construction and remodeling for many years you have a tough path forward, we flipped a few homes and removed existing wall coverings put up new sheetrock because of crappy DIY patch jobs or texture that was dated, so this may be a tough path forward for you. I state this because I bet I could find mold in my current home and did in my last home that the inspectors mmissed. So unless you can prove they knew and not only about moisture but there was dangerous mold that many don't have a clue about you may be wasting $ to fix on lawyers